# $().text(); Not Getting Changed Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So I'm working on an app where I need what the user enters to be transferred to another element after being processed. However when I try to grab the `.text()` value of the `<textarea>`, it simply returns whatever the value was when the page first loaded.

The problem lies in the `formatcss.js` and `index.html` files

**Github Repo** - http://github.com/JordanAdams/Prefixrr

**Live App** - http://jordanadams.github.com/Prefixrr

Thanks,
Jordan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `.val()` instead of `.text()`

```
${'#textareaid').val();
```

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks for the quick response :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to grab the `.val()` not `.text()`

http://jsfiddle.net/nJgN6/5/